# Angular 7 - PDF file not opening

Tags: cakephp, angular7, pdf-viewer

I am using Angular 7 for front end application and CakePHP for backend. On click of a button, a pdf file should open in the new tab. When I am trying to open it, instead of opening pdf file(url:"**http://localhost/api/report/1234.pdf**"), it is throwing error message - "**Missing controller**". It seems browser is unable to detect pdf file

Please find the package.json file below

```
{
```

"name": "xyz",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^7.2.16",
"@angular/cdk": "~7.3.7",
"@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
"@cds/core": "^5.6.4",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^1.1.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^12.4.0",
"@clr/angular": "^1.1.2",
"@clr/icons": "^1.1.2",
"@clr/ui": "^1.1.2",
"@fullcalendar/angular": "^4.2.1",
"@fullcalendar/core": "^4.2.0",
"@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.2.0",
"@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.2.0",
"@fullcalendar/resource-timegrid": "^4.2.0",
"@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.2.0",
"@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.20.5",
"@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.6.0",
"angular-ng-autocomplete": "^1.1.14",
"blueimp-canvas-to-blob": "^3.17.0",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"file-saver": "^2.0.2",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"log4js": "^6.3.0",
"ng-http-loader": "^5.1.0",
"ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.4",
"ng2-image-compress": "^7.0.7",
"ng2-img-max": "^2.1.18",
"ng2-pdf-viewer": "~6.4.1",
"ngx-filter-pipe": "^2.1.2",
"ngx-pagination": "^4.1.0",
"ngx-select-ex": "^7.0.1",
"ngx-toastr": "^10.2.0",
"rxjs": "~6.3.3",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"zone.js": "~0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
"@angular/cli": "~7.3.8",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~4.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"node-sass": "^7.0.1",
"protractor": "~5.4.0",
"ts-node": "~7.0.0",
"tslint": "~5.11.0",
"typescript": "~3.2.2",
"webpack": "^4.29.0"
}
}

Comment: Please share the routing configuration that you have set up to handle routes like `/api/report/1234.pdf` in your application.

Comment: Hello Greg. You want the routing from Angular side or cakephp side?

Comment: "Missing controller" seems like a Cake error, so that's the routing that would seem to matter here.

Comment: Please find the routes.php below. I have checked on server it's the same routes.php file. It is working fine on server but not on local

Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'employees', 'action' => 'home'));
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
CakePlugin::routes();
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';

Comment: I'm not seeing anything there that would obviously handle "/api" routes specially, so it'll by default want to send that to an "ApiController". Do you have such a controller, with a "report" function in it?

Comment: Application is built on older version of cakephp. couldn't find any controller with "report" function

Comment: If you don't have code to handle this particular URL, what's your expectation of how it's going to be processed?

Comment: It should open pdf file instead of going into controller. Working fine on server but when I’m trying from localhost it’s not working. I’ve limited knowledge about cakephp. My task is to open pdf file on click of a button in new tab but it’s going into controller instead of opening when I’m trying from localhost but working fine for live servers

Comment: So this is a PDF file that already exists in the filesystem and it should just be returned as is? If so, this is nothing about Angular or Cake, but rather your web server configuration, e.g. `.htaccess` or the like should not be sending this request to Cake at all.

Comment: 1)<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /api/
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
2)<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
    php_value post_max_size 1024M
    php_value upload_max_filesize 1024M
 </IfModule>
3)<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /api/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>